# Creating A Class That wraps AWS SDK

Tags: php, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I am using the AWS PHP SDK. Typically, I would do something like this in my program:

```
require '/aws_sdk/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Rds\RdsClient; 
use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

try {
    $ec2Client = new Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => 'us-west-1,
        'profile' => 'default'
    ]); 
} catch (Ec2Exception $ex) {
    pretty_echo($ex->getMessage());
}
```

What I would like to do instead, is write a class that uses Aws\Rds\RdsClient, Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client and Aws\Exception\AwsException.

Following is my namespace (esd_aws_sdk.php):

```
<?php

namespace Esd\AwsSdk;
require PHP_BASE.'/aws_sdk/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Rds\RdsClient; 
use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

class Clients
{  
    public $region;
    public $profile;
    public $Ec2Client = FALSE;
    public $RdsClient = FALSE;
    
    function __construct($region, $profile) {
        $this->region = $region;
        $this->profile = $profile;
        $this->createAwsClients();
    }
    
    private function createAwsClients()
    {
        {
            try {
                $this->Ec2Client = new Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client([
                    'version' => 'latest',
                    'region' => $this->region,
                    'profile' => $this->profile
                ]); 
            } catch (Ec2Exception $ex) {
                echo($ex->getMessage());
            }
        }    
        try {
            $this->RdsClient = new Aws\Rds\RdsClient([
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region' => $this->region,
                'profile' => $this->profile
            ]);    
        } catch (RdsException $ex) {
            echo($ex->getMessage());
        }        
    }
}
```

And the test program: test.php

```
<?php

SetPaths();
include_once 'aws_sdk.php';
use Esd\AwsSdk;

$AwsClients = new Esd\AwsSdk\Clients('us-east-1', 'airtable');

function SetPaths()
{
    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $dir = explode($ds, __DIR__);
    $dir_last_key = count($dir) - 1;
    unset($dir[$dir_last_key]);
    $app_root = implode($ds, $dir);
    define('APP_CODE',$app_root.$ds.'code'.$ds);
    define('APP_INCLUDE',$app_root.$ds.'include'.$ds);
    define('APP_DATA',$app_root.$ds.'data'.$ds);
    define('APP_LOG',$app_root.$ds.'log'.$ds);
    unset($dir[$dir_last_key - ($depth + 1)]);
    define('SECTION_COMMON',implode($ds, $dir).$ds.'common'.$ds);
    unset($dir[$dir_last_key - ($depth +2)]);
    define('PHP_BASE',implode($ds, $dir).$ds);    
}
```

But when I run test.php, I get the following:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Esd\AwsSdk\Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client' not found in /Users/esd-mac/php/aws/aws/code/aws_sdk.php:26 
Stack trace: #0 /Users/esd-mac/php/aws/aws/code/aws_sdk.php(19): Esd\AwsSdk\Clients->createAwsClients() #1 /Users/esd-mac/php/aws/aws/code/test.php(7): Esd\AwsSdk\Clients->__construct('us-east-1', 'airtable') #2 {main} thrown in /Users/esd-mac/php/aws/aws/code/aws_sdk.php on line 26
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough. Going back to the basics though, the PHP parser doesn't seem to think it can find the class file with how you've laid it out. I think we'd need to see more to get a good answer out of this, however I'd try a few troubleshooting steps:

1. You're using the same class member name as you are Class name ($this->Ec2Client = new Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client) which makes your job of debugging harder. Even if only for the time you're building, I would change to something like `$this->computeClient = Ec2Client`
2. It's hard to tell if your Use statement is correctly working, especially when you call the entire namespace in the `new` call. I would change the Use statement to something like `Use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client as Ec2Client;` so that you can say `= new Ec2Client`. At that point your errors will look slightly more meaningful, as they'll tell you if Ec2Client means anything (and verify that the Use statement has the correct path)
3. If I had to guess, PHP thinks you are trying to access `Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client` inside the `Esd/AwsSdk` namespace. Try adding a leading slash to inform PHP that you are loading from the root (`\Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client`)

Comment: I needed to add a leading slash to inform PHP that I am loading from the root (\Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client) and (\Aws\Rds\RdsClient) when I created each client